# Filter strings into list depending on position - Python

Tags: python, html, regex

For example, this is my string:

```
myString = "<html><body><p>Hello World!</p><p>Hello Dennis!</p></body></html>"
```

and what i am trying to achieve is:

```
myList = ['Hello World!','Hello Dennis!']
```

Using regular expressions or another method, how can i filter out paragraph text out of `myString` while ignoring the html tags to achieve `myList`?

I have tried:

```
import re
a="<body><p>Hello world!</p><p>Hello Denniss!</p></body>"
result=re.search('<p>(.*)</p>', a)
print result.group(1)
```

Which resulted in: `Hello world!</p><p>Hello Denniss!` and when i tried `(.*)(.*)` i got `Hello World!`

This string is just an example. The string may also be `<garbage>abcdefghijk<gar<bage>` depending on how the web developer coded the website.

It may be a complex regex, but i need to learn this as it is for a cyber security competition i will be participating in later this year and i think my best bet is to develop an algorithm which searches for text between a `>` and a `<`.

How would i go about this?

Sorry if my question is not formatted properly, i have a bit of learning problems.

Comment: [Always relevant about Regex and HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/572845)

Comment: @TyrantWave [**FWIW**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182189)

Comment: @HamZa - eh, I don't really agree with that meta, especially when the question is about extracting text (Which regex does fail miserably at). I'd certainly never link it as an answer, at least without giving a full explanation. Comments are just that - a comment on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to get rid of all tags in a `html` text? I won't choose regular expression, better *the other method*, for example with `BeautifulSoup` and you will surprise all in that hacking meeting:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

myString = "<html><body><p>Hello World!</p><p>Hello Dennis!</p></body></html>"

myList = list(BeautifulSoup(myString).strings))
```

It yields:

```
['Hello World!', 'Hello Dennis!']
```

Comment: thankyou for that, it is really useful..

does it matter that i am getting it in unicode? 

eg [u'Hello',u'World!']

Comment: @vjgaero: As far as I know it's correct. `BeautifulSoup` decodes them when extracting from `html` code.

Answer (score 1):

HTML parsing with regex is definitly [limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not/590789#590789), but if you'd like to have real solution of HTML mining try to look at this addon [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

As for your regex, the `asterisk` quantifier is *greedy* it will gorge until the last of `</p>`. So, you should use `(?=XXX)` command which means *search until XXX found*.

Try the following:

```
re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)(?=</p>)', s)
```